# Read the score from a file and calculate average grade for each students?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input, jupyter

I want to process a text file by using Python.

#studentdata.txt

```
joe 10 15 20 30 40 
bill 23 16 19 22 
sue 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
grace 12 28 21 45 26 10
john 14 32 25 16 18
```

Then write a program that calculates the average grade for each student, and print out the student’s name along with their average grade with two decimal places.

Below are my codes:

```
enter import os
f = open(os.path.abspath('/Users/adong850408/Downloads/studentdata.txt'),"r")
words = f.readlines()

k=[]
for i in words:
split_i = i.split()
k.append(split_i)

for j in k:
    for int(n) in j[1: ]:
         print(sum(int(n)),len(n))
f.close()
```

My idea is to create a list k, then insert studentdata.txt into list k. However, I am facing some questions :

1. I have used int(), but can not convert strings to integers.
2. How to calculate the average grade for each student?
3. How to print out the student’s name along with their average grade.

Comment: Your code does not run as-is. Do you have a version that runs? It would be easier to start from there.

Comment: Below is the result after I run the codes. Obviously, it was stuck at when converting strings to integers. 

Input In [46]
    for int(n) in j[1: ]:
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex, maybe you can try this and see if you have any further questions:

It's to get the scores and strip, process the average step-by-step.

```py
filename = 'studentdata.txt'

# since the scores file is so small, it's fine to do this:
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open(filename, 'r') ] # get all records in one shot


for line in lines:
    ll = line.split()        # each is a student's record (string), so it needs to break into parts
    #print(ll)
    name, *scores = ll       # unpacking

    print(name, scores)      # to confirm, uncomment later.

    total = sum(int(x) for x in scores)
    average = total / len(scores)
    print(name, ": ", total, average)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was stuck at not knowing how to operate average because each line includes string and numbers, but when I saw the unpacking line " name, *score = ll ", I found that this is the solution I had sought for a long time.  Again, thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: Sure, no problem!! I have marked it, thank you, Daniel!!!

Comment: Welcome to the learning *journey* .  Ask some more good questions, when you got confused/stuck... ;-)